# Python: Emit signal to all instances if class method is called?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyside

I have a lot of buttons of the same type (derived from `QPushButton`) over many different pages and forms. I want a global switch to change a property of instances, for example enable/disable all. Is it possible to call a class method for this target. An idea is to save every new reference (`__new__`/`__init__`?) in a static array, but is there a pythonic and garbage collector compatible way? The standard recursive searching from root (main window) to the last corner would be terrible.

Using: Python 3.3 + pyside + Qt4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
class MyButton(QPushButton):

    BigSwitch = SomeQObjectThatDefinesTheSignal()

    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        BigSwitch.the_signal.connect(self.some_slot)

    def some_slot(self, ...):
        #handle the change of the property

    @classmethod
    def enable(cls):
        cls.BigSwitch.the_signal.emit(...)
```

You could also use a `staticmethod` and `MyButton.BigSwitch` instead of a class method.